# Websocket connection failed. Chatsocket closed

Tags: python, html, django, websocket, django-channels

Using django channels im trying to connect to a websocket but it can't find it. I tried to see if its because of routing.py or consumer.py and i can't find the answer. I get the warning that no route was found for path 'tribechat/1/'.

***git error message:***

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\andri\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\channels\staticfiles.py", line 44, in __call__
    return await self.application(scope, receive, send)
  File "C:\Users\andri\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\channels\routing.py", line 71, in __call__
    return await application(scope, receive, send)
  File "C:\Users\andri\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\channels\security\websocket.py", line 37, in __call__
    return await self.application(scope, send, receive)
  File "C:\Users\andri\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\channels\sessions.py", line 47, in __call__
    return await self.inner(dict(scope, cookies=cookies), receive, send)
  File "C:\Users\andri\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\channels\sessions.py", line 254, in __call__
    return await self.inner(wrapper.scope, receive, wrapper.send)
  File "C:\Users\andri\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\channels\auth.py", line 181, in __call__
    return await super().__call__(scope, receive, send)
  File "C:\Users\andri\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\channels\middleware.py", line 26, in __call__
    return await self.inner(scope, receive, send)
  File "C:\Users\andri\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\channels\routing.py", line 168, in __call__
    raise ValueError("No route found for path %r." % path)
ValueError: No route found for path 'tribe_chat/1/'.
```

***Console error message:***

**WebSocket connection to 'ws://127.0.0.1:8000/tribe_chat/1/' failed:**

***routing.py:***

```
from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
from channels.security.websocket import AllowedHostsOriginValidator
from django.urls import path, re_path

from tribe_chat.consumers import TribeChatConsumer

application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    'websocket': AllowedHostsOriginValidator(
        AuthMiddlewareStack(
            URLRouter([
                    re_path(r'ws/tribe_chat/(?P<room_id>\w+)/$', TribeChatConsumer.as_asgi()),
            ])
        )
    ),
})
```

***consumers.py:***

```
from channels.generic.websocket import AsyncJsonWebsocketConsumer
import json
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

User = get_user_model()

class TribeChatConsumer(AsyncJsonWebsocketConsumer):

    async def connect(self):
        print("TribeChatConsumer: connect: " + str(self.scope["user"]))
        await self.accept()

        await self.channel_layer.group_add(
            "tribe_chatroom_1",
            self.channel_name,
        )


    async def disconnect(self, code):
        print("TribeChatConsumer: disconnect")
        pass
```

***tribe_chat_form.html:***

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    setupTribeChatWebSocket()

    function setupTribeChatWebSocket(){
        // Correctly decide between ws:// and wss://
        var ws_scheme = window.location.protocol == "https:" ? "wss" : "ws";
        var ws_path = ws_scheme + '://' + window.location.host + "/tribe_chat/{{room_id}}/"; // development
        var tribe_chat_socket = new WebSocket(ws_path);
```

Answer (score 0):

From your URLRouter, it is supposed to be `ws/tribe_chat/1/` but you try to connect to `tribe_chat/1/` omitting the `ws` in front. Either remove the `ws` from the router or prepend it to the client address